# C# Split and Store Strings into Data table -- Then Compare 2 Data tables

Tags: c#, mysql, string

I have a string that looks like this

```
"Start Date: 



2015-1-1 



End Date: 

 2017-1-1 



Warranty Type: 

 XXX 



Status: 

 Active 



Serial Number/IMEI: 

 XXXXXXXX









Description:



This product has a three year limited warranty and is entitled to parts, labor and on-site repair service. Service is available Monday-Friday, except holidays, with a next business day response objective. Many parts can also be delivered to you using the Customer Replaceable Unit (CRU) method."
```

I would like to store "2015-1-1" "2017-1-1" "Active" in my Data table- How is this done?

Once that process is done I want to compare the data I have stored to my original data table and see if the dates and status' match (if they dont I create a report alerting the user there is a date that is wrong).

Edit: I have around 300~ of these strings so I am not sure what the best way to handle that amount of strings is.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
var parts = s.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var startDate = DateTime.Parse(parts.SkipWhile(p => p != "Start Date:").Skip(1).First().Trim());
var endDate = DateTime.Parse(parts.SkipWhile(p => p != "EndDate:").Skip(1).First().Trim());
var status = parts.SkipWhile(p => p != "Status:").Skip(1).First();
```

then, having these values, you may insert them into your data table

Comment: shouldn't I convert those dates to a DateTime? I am getting an error that says cannot convert string to char in (Environment.NewLine)

Comment: if you mean that there might be some empty lines between "start date" and the date itself, or some spaces before/after the date, check my answer edits one more time

Comment: I updated my string to exactly what I get back from the website's html that im pulling from

Comment: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll

Additional information: Sequence contains no elements" Seem to be getting this error on var startDate

Comment: yes because in my code it is "EndDate", should be "End Date"

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect solution for Regular Expressions.

EDIT: Since OP updated his input string, I updated my code and regular expression pattern to match.

```
string var1 =
@"Start Date: 



2015 - 1 - 1



End Date: 

 2017 - 1 - 1



Warranty Type: 

 XXX



Status: 

 Active



Serial Number / IMEI: 

 XXXXXXXX









Description:



This product has a three year limited warranty and is entitled to parts, labor and on-site repair service. Service is available Monday - Friday, except holidays, with a next business day response objective. Many parts can also be delivered to you using the Customer Replaceable Unit (CRU)method.";

// Remove all spaces and newlines
var1 = var1.Replace(" ", "").Replace("\r\n", "");

// our regex pattern now that there ar eno spaces or new lines
var regex = new Regex(@"StartDate:(.*)EndDate:(.*)W.*Status:(.*)\/");                   

//assign them
string strStartDate = regex.Match(var1).Groups[1].ToString();
string strEndDate = regex.Match(var1).Groups[2].ToString();
string Status = regex.Match(var1).Groups[3].ToString().Substring(0, 6);

//convert to DateTime from our string versions
DateTime StartDate = DateTime.Parse(strStartDate);
DateTime EndDate = DateTime.Parse(strEndDate);
```

Comment: I edited the string to what I actually return (I am parsing a html div and taking the .InnerText) - Would this still apply?

Comment: If you changed what's in var1 you may need a new regex pattern. Check this page out: https://regex101.com/ - I used that to create this pattern. With your new values you should be able to figure out a new pattern. If you need help from there, just ask

Comment: I will take a look, thanks for taking the time to help !

Comment: @Havoux, I updated the regular expression to match the new string you posted

Comment: I actually have an issue with getting "Active" - the problem is there is a chance that I get "Inactive" as a result aswell so substring(0, 6) would return "inacti" - Any other solutions to this?

Comment: There's probably a cleaner way to do this but you could do:                                               string Status = regex.Match(var1).Groups[3].ToString().ToUpper().StartsWith("IN") ? "Inactive" : "Active";